# How do I change url in .wxs file with build configuration

Tags: wix, installation

I have a Wix install project in Visual Studio 2012 and have an xml node like

```
<MsiPackage ... DownloadUrl="http://uat.mywebsite.com/MyMSI.msi">
```

I want to change the url depending on the build configuration. i.e. in uat I want it to be http://uat.mywebsite.com/... and in release http://mywebsite.com/...

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your WiX project has access to build parameters, like the Configuration (`debug` or `release`). You can conditionally include the correct `DownloadUrl` for the current configuration by referencing `$(var.Configuartion)` in your component declarations:

Not tested this but something similar should work:

```
 <?if $(var.Configuartion) = Release?>
 <?define DownloadUrl = "http://uat.mywebsite.com/" ?>
 <?elseif $(var.Configuartion) = Debug?>
 <?define DownloadUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/" ?>     
 <?endif ?>

 <MsiPackage ... DownloadUrl="$(var.DownloadURL)">
```